# When I Installing library, react gives an error

Tags: reactjs

I have problem Most of the time, When I wants to install any new library to my react project. it shows me error. I attached the error image. Now I run this command to install react-social-icons

```
npm i react-social-icons
```

It shows me this error. what is it error means and how can i get rid from this. please help me Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Looks like `react-social-icons` doesn't support your react version (yet)

Comment: Try to use `--force` command: `npm i react-social-icons --force`

Comment: @mousetail Thanks for guide why error generated.

Comment: @mikenlanggio Thanks for how to resolved the error, now its working with --force.